# Interrupted apt, now cannot use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, kernel, initramfs

I am running dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with NVIDIA GPU:s and stupidly forced my computer to shut down during an Ubuntu apt installation, as I mistook it for a crash (screen turned black followed by a terminal) without looking too much into it. Since this, I have not been able to use as the system freezes entirely when reaching the login screen (I am already using nomodeset). Booting into recovery mode from GRUB menu does not work either, it freezes upon getting the recovery menu.

##### Attempts of Fixing

To try to fix this, I managed to boot directly into a root bash session by pressing `e` in GRUB when booting Ubuntu and appending `rw init=/bin/bash` to the line beginning with linux. From here I was able to remove some unrelated datasets to free up space on my hard drive, and then ran `dpkg --configure -a`. After this, trying to boot my Ubuntu on my default latest kernel still does not work, but instead of freezing at login it stops at an `initramfs` terminal that says `gave up waiting for root file system device`.

After trying the suggested diagnostics given by initramfs, increasing rootdelay did not work, and /proc/modules was empty, and ls /dev did not show stuff like sda. No luck there.

I then tried to boot from a previous kernel (my latest kernel is 4.15.0.151 and the previous kernel is 4.15.0.147), and I do manage to not get stuck at initramfs, but now I again get a freeze at login. This is as far as I have gotten in trying to fix things, and hopefully it hasn't ruined stuff for me. Booting recovery mode via the GRUB menu on this kernel still does not work, but booting directly to a root bash session works (have not tried gaining internet access in this root bash session, not sure how to do so).

Right now, I have managed to boot an 18.04 LTS installer from a USB. This does not have the option to reinstall with existing file system, but it does allow me to access the file system, which seems to work just fine. I was able to access logs for apt that occurred right before I first forced shut down during apt installations, and below are logs for the day of the apt install. Note that in both of these logs, at the end, they are interrupted. I also see that it was interrupted during nvidia updates, and that some initramfs was deferred but intended to be modified right before being interrupted (could explain the initramfs issues I am having when booting on 4.15.0.151).

##### Question

I am wondering if it is possible for me to save my existing Ubuntu installation, maybe by rolling back the apt installations or somehow restoring or fixing the initramfs stuff, or even just getting the previous kernel 4.15.0.147 to work?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if any other logs are needed.

##### Logs

/var/log/apt/term.log

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-myhostname_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-myhostname:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Setting up libnss-myhostname:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:05:51

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:05:54
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-common-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-common-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:05:55

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:05:58
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-151.157_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-151.157) over (4.15.0-147.151) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:05:58

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:06:02
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-signed-generic_4.15.0.151.139_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-generic (4.15.0.151.139) over (4.15.0.147.134) ...
Setting up linux-signed-generic (4.15.0.151.139) ...
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:06:02

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:06:07
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd-sysv_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:06:08

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:06:12
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libudev-dev_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev-dev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Preparing to unpack .../udev_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Setting up udev (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libudev-dev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-147-generic
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:06:24

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:06:27
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-systemd_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-systemd_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd0_237-3ubuntu10.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) over (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.49) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:06:31

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:06:34
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.15.0-151-generic.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 427029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-linux-modules-4.15.0-151-generic_4.15.0-151.157_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../1-linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic_4.15.0-151.157_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-151-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../2-linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-151-generic_4.15.0-151.157_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-linux-generic_4.15.0.151.139_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.15.0.151.139) over (4.15.0.147.134) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-linux-image-generic_4.15.0.151.139_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.15.0.151.139) over (4.15.0.147.134) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.15.0-151.
Preparing to unpack .../5-linux-headers-4.15.0-151_4.15.0-151.157_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-151 (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../6-linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic_4.15.0-151.157_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.151.139_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.151.139) over (4.15.0.147.134) ...
Setting up linux-modules-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-151 (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-151-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch disable_fstack-clash-protection_fcf-protection.patch...patching file Kbuild
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 (offset 11 lines).


Building module:
cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j8 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.15.0-151-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules........
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/460.80/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/460.80/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-drm.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/460.80/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-modeset.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/460.80/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia-uvm.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=4.15.0-151-generic -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.42/build.....
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.42/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/vboxnetadp.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.42/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/vboxpci.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.42/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/vboxdrv.ko
 - /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.42/4.15.0-151-generic/x86_64/module/vboxnetflt.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-151-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
   ...done.
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.151.139) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-147-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-147-generic
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-151-generic
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-151-generic
Setting up linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.15.0.151.139) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.15.0.151.139) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic (4.15.0-151.157) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-151-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-151-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-151-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-151-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-147-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-147-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-144-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-144-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Log ended: 2021-07-21  10:07:32

Log started: 2021-07-21  10:07:36
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 462584 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-nvidia-driver-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-gl-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-nvidia-dkms-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-nvidia-kernel-source-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-nvidia-kernel-common-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnvidia-decode-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnvidia-compute-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnvidia-extra-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-extra-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-nvidia-compute-utils-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-encode-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-nvidia-utils-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-libnvidia-ifr1-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libnvidia-fbc1-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-libnvidia-cfg1-460_460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnvidia-extra-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-utils-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-147-generic
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-147-generic
```

/var/log/apt/history.log

```
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libnss-myhostname:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:05:51

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:05:54
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libnvidia-common-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:05:55

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:05:58
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-147.151, 4.15.0-151.157)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:05:58

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:02
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.147.134, 4.15.0.151.139)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:02

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:07
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: systemd-sysv:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:08

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:12
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: udev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49), libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49), libudev-dev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:24

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:27
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49), libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49), systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49), libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.44, 237-3ubuntu10.49)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:31

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:06:34
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-151.157, automatic), linux-modules-4.15.0-151-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-151.157, automatic), linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-151.157, automatic), linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-151-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-151.157, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-151:amd64 (4.15.0-151.157, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.147.134, 4.15.0.151.139), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.147.134, 4.15.0.151.139), linux-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.147.134, 4.15.0.151.139)
End-Date: 2021-07-21  10:07:32

Start-Date: 2021-07-21  10:07:36
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libnvidia-compute-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libnvidia-encode-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), nvidia-kernel-common-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libnvidia-gl-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libnvidia-decode-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), nvidia-utils-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), nvidia-dkms-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), nvidia-driver-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libnvidia-extra-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), nvidia-kernel-source-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

**EDIT 1**: After running `sudo fsck UUID=<uuid of my unmounted target file system>`, the result is `/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 1322236/9601024 files, 32166204/38392320 blocks`

Comment: You don't say if Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop or 18.04 Server; but Ubuntu 18.04 desktop does allow you to re-install without format; it's offered via "*Something else*" where you can fully control what you want to do.  If you didn't clean shutdown (ie. Sysrq commands to force shutdown; but I'm unsure how you forced shutdown so if a safe method OR unsafe like power-off) I'd start by `fsck` or file-system check from *live* media,.. then reboot & login only to text terminal and try and have it complete what it was doing..  when completed; reboot & try and use normally (which I'd expect that to work)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop! I forced shutdown by holding down the power button on the computer until it turned off. What do you mean by using fsck from live media? What is meant by live media in particular? I am currently on "Try Ubuntu 18.04" system, and can access my original file system but not with root access

Comment: @guiverc I tried to run fsck from the system I am on now, but it say I do not have r/w access to the filesystem! I have not been able to fsck on the target (broken) system either when I boot directly to a root bash session, since it says I cannot fsck on a filesystem I have mounted

Comment: By booting a *live* system (eg. Ubuntu install media and using the "*Try Ubuntu*" option, only the thumb-drive (*live* media will be mounted) allowing `fsck` or your installed system - why I said *live* media.  You can use `gparted` or `gnome-disks` (GUI tools) or use a terminal and elevate privileges using `sudo`, but if newbie I'd suggest using the GUI tools (`gparted`, `gnome-disks` to `fsck` your hdd/ssd system; do remember the running system is your *live* media; or trial-system so `fsck` your system that exists on your hdd/ssd)

Comment: @guiverc ah, I understand now! I added the results of fsck on my target filesystem to the original post as an edit. The results look similar to what I have seen during bootup throughout the debugging process, but despite getting this result my problem still persists when I try to boot my original Ubuntu.

Comment: I suspect that something has gone wrong in the initramfs or nvidia stuff based on the unfortunate timing of my shutdown in the logs, which could have messed up my ability to boot initramfs on the main kernel and also causes the freeze on login screen for the older kernel. Or maybe I am way off?

Comment: @guiverc I managed to fix it, I posted my fix as an answer, thank you so much for the help and discussion!! It got me to think more about using mounting :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicions were correct; my system wanted to install new nvidia drivers (and it also decided to upgrade to a new kernel while at it I think but not as sure on this one). When I interrupted the installation by forcing shutdown, the installation was in the process of writing to initrd.img using update-initramfs. Hence the "freeze at login screen" and "stuck at initramfs" - they were both signs of what was wrong!

I managed to fix it and gain complete control of my original Ubuntu system including the original filesystem :) here's how I did it:

##### DISCLAIMER

**Try this at your own risk!** I did this while not caring if my original Ubuntu filesystem breaks. Having said that, this worked fine for me and I never actually felt as if my filesystem was at risk of breaking. And in the end it didn't break as far as I know - **the filesystem was not broken before I did this (see EDIT 1 with fsck in the question) and is not broken after. You should make sure that the filesystem itself is not broken if you want to try this fix.**

##### Fix

**In summary, my fix involved using an Ubuntu install USB and use the trial version to access the filesystem and fix its broken apt installations. Please read the full fix before attempting it!**

First, I got the Ubuntu bootable USB stick that I used to install Ubuntu in the first place (you can just re-download this from the Ubuntu website if you no longer have it, try to have the same Ubuntu-version though, 18.04 LTS in my case). I inserted it into the computer and, through BIOS, selected the USB stick as the boot option. Then, I was presented with GRUB from the USB stick, and selected the "Try Ubuntu" option. This starts a "trial version" of Ubuntu.

From here, I followed **parts** of [this link](https://linoxide.com/fixing-broken-initrd-image-linux/) to find the filesystem of my original Ubuntu system (the one I want to recover, not the trial version), mount it and prepare it so that I can update apt stuff on that filesystem.

> I actually went through all instructions in that tutorial at first, but it did not fix my problem. However, the steps I outlined below are what I did to fix things and they worked for me.

For the sake of completeness, I will summarize the parts I followed below:

1. Start a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T. Go to root by doing `cd /`.
2. Use `sudo fdisk -l` to find out what your filesystem path is (in my case it was `/dev/nvme0n1p5` but it can also be `/dev/sdaX` for some number X).
3. Use `sudo mount <path from step 2> /mnt` (again, in my case the path was `/dev/nvme0n1p5`). This mounts the filesystem of the original Ubuntu system so that it is accessible from the trial Ubuntu through `/mnt`.
4. Use `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`, `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc` and `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`. No idea why this is done but I did it to follow the tutorial and it worked for me.
5. Use `sudo chroot /mnt` to create a temporary environment that has the original filesystem as the root. I would imagine this helps reconfiguration occur properly and not on the trial system.

Now, you should have a terminal prompt `#` that waits for further instructions. This means you are in the temporary environment with changed root.

From here, I followed **parts** of [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-without-reinstalling/) to fix my messed up apt installations and initramfs. I did NOT do the stuff from that tutorial that is related to locks. To summarize, I did the following from this tutorial:

6. Use `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
7. Use `sudo apt clean`
8. Use `sudo apt update --fix-missing`
9. Use `sudo apt install -f`
10. Use `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (yes, again according to their tutorial :p)
11. Use `sudo apt upgrade`
12. Use `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
13. If you see any trouble with things not being upgraded or installed, look up what the error related to that trouble is, and how to fix that so you can successfully upgrade.

After doing this, you should be able to get your NVIDIA drivers upgraded and it should also generate a clean initrd.img file which is what caused the "stuck at initramfs" problem for me! Finally, to finish up and reboot, I did the following cleanup described in the first tutorial:

14. Use `update-grub`
15. Use `exit` to exit the temporary environment with changed root; you should now have a "standard" terminal prompt and be out of the environment.
16. Use `sudo umount /mnt/dev`
17. Use `sudo umount /mnt/proc`
18. Use `sudo umount /mnt/sys`
19. Use `sudo umount /mnt`

This unmounts the original filesystem. I then turned off the computer, booted up GRUB for my original Ubuntu system (not the trial Ubuntu bootable USB), and selected the normal first option.

And it worked! No freezes and no being stuck at initramfs. :)

Hope this helps someone, but remember the disclaimer!

Answer (score 1):

With 4.15.0-151 it's 2 days I'm experiencing a lot of troubles too.
My Ubuntu 18.04 LTS continues to hang randomly. Then I need to restart in maintenance mode, check filesystems, fix the errors, then reboot normally.
After 4 hangs in few minutes, I reverted to 4.15.0-147 that works correctly.
There's something broken in build 151 for sure.

This is what I found in journal after a reboot forced by a system hang. It never happened with 4.15.0-147:

```
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff913c0fee15bc
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: IP: __kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x142/0x2b0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Modules linked in: vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) ccm cmac rfcomm bnep zram binfmt_misc intel_rapl x86_pkg_tem
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  input_leds serio_raw fb_sys_fops snd_seq snd_seq_device syscopyarea snd_timer shpchp snd sysfillrect soundcore mei_me me
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 10386 Comm: Socket Thread Tainted: P        W  OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Hardware name: Acer Aspire E5-771G/EA70_HB, BIOS V1.07 06/04/2014
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RIP: 0010:__kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x142/0x2b0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffad0500987bb8 EFLAGS: 00010282
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RAX: ffff913c0fee15bc RBX: 00000000014102c0 RCX: ffffffff9d85a077
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RDX: 000000000000a81a RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000026180
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RBP: ffffad0500987bf8 R08: ffff91e25f226180 R09: ffff91e25a802d80
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff91e25a802d80 R12: 00000000014102c0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R13: 0000000000000800 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: ffff913c0fee15bc
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: FS:  00007f0e53755700(0000) GS:ffff91e25f200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CR2: ffff913c0fee15bc CR3: 000000015460e001 CR4: 00000000001606f0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Call Trace:
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? __alloc_skb+0x87/0x1d0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  __kmalloc_reserve.isra.43+0x31/0x90
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? tcp_v4_md5_lookup+0x13/0x20
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  __alloc_skb+0x87/0x1d0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  sk_stream_alloc_skb+0x56/0x1f0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  tcp_sendmsg_locked+0x515/0xec0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  tcp_sendmsg+0x2c/0x50
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  inet_sendmsg+0x2e/0xb0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  sock_sendmsg+0x3e/0x50
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  SYSC_sendto+0x13f/0x180
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? SyS_futex+0x13b/0x180
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  SyS_sendto+0xe/0x10
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f0e53419a9e
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RSP: 002b:00007f0e537540b0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00000000000000ac RCX: 00007f0e53419a9e
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RDX: 0000000000000060 RSI: 00007f0e0f4a2000 RDI: 00000000000000ac
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f0e0f4a2000
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R13: 0000000000000060 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Code: 4c 89 df 4c 89 5d c8 e8 bd ae 01 00 49 89 c1 4c 8b 5d c8 4d 85 c9 0f 85 35 ff ff ff 45 31 ff eb 4e 49 63 41 20 49 8
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RIP: __kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x142/0x2b0 RSP: ffffad0500987bb8
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CR2: ffff913c0fee15bc
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: ---[ end trace be1d19e661060db7 ]---
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff913c0fee15bc
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: IP: __kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x142/0x2b0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Oops: 0000 [#2] SMP PTI
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Modules linked in: vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) ccm cmac rfcomm bnep zram binfmt_misc intel_rapl x86_pkg_tem
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  input_leds serio_raw fb_sys_fops snd_seq snd_seq_device syscopyarea snd_timer shpchp snd sysfillrect soundcore mei_me me
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 10382 Comm: IPC I/O Parent Tainted: P      D W  OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Hardware name: Acer Aspire E5-771G/EA70_HB, BIOS V1.07 06/04/2014
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RIP: 0010:__kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x142/0x2b0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffad0500753a98 EFLAGS: 00010282
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RAX: ffff913c0fee15bc RBX: 00000000015102c0 RCX: ffffffff9d85a077
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RDX: 000000000000a81a RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000026180
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RBP: ffffad0500753ad8 R08: ffff91e25f226180 R09: ffff91e25a802d80
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R10: ffffad0500753d58 R11: ffff91e25a802d80 R12: 00000000015102c0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R13: 0000000000000740 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: ffff913c0fee15bc
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: FS:  00007f0e53818700(0000) GS:ffff91e25f200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CR2: ffff913c0fee15bc CR3: 000000015460e003 CR4: 00000000001606f0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Call Trace:
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? __alloc_skb+0x87/0x1d0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  __kmalloc_reserve.isra.43+0x31/0x90
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  __alloc_skb+0x87/0x1d0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  alloc_skb_with_frags+0x56/0x1b0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  sock_alloc_send_pskb+0x1f2/0x220
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x40
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? wait_for_unix_gc+0x37/0xb0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  unix_stream_sendmsg+0x1b6/0x390
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  sock_sendmsg+0x3e/0x50
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ___sys_sendmsg+0x2a0/0x2f0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? get_futex_key+0x2f7/0x3b0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? touch_atime+0x36/0xe0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? futex_wake+0x8f/0x180
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? do_futex+0x18f/0x4e0
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  __sys_sendmsg+0x54/0x90
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  ? __sys_sendmsg+0x54/0x90
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  SyS_sendmsg+0x12/0x20
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f0e5341a6f7
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RSP: 002b:00007f0e538136d0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000000000000007b RCX: 00007f0e5341a6f7
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RDX: 0000000000000040 RSI: 00007f0e53813770 RDI: 000000000000007b
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RBP: 00007f0e53813770 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f0df2bda380
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R10: 00007f0df723c59c R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000040
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: R13: 00007f0e53813750 R14: 00007f0e2a4db1a0 R15: 0000000000000001
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: Code: 4c 89 df 4c 89 5d c8 e8 bd ae 01 00 49 89 c1 4c 8b 5d c8 4d 85 c9 0f 85 35 ff ff ff 45 31 ff eb 4e 49 63 41 20 49 8
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: RIP: __kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x142/0x2b0 RSP: ffffad0500753a98
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: CR2: ffff913c0fee15bc
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: ---[ end trace be1d19e661060db8 ]---
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff913c0fee15bc
lug 23 15:11:17 Lucifer kernel: IP: __kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x142/0x2b0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1938013) about this problem, with a proposed [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1938013/comments/22).